# The expected log-Likelihood in Kullback Leibler Divergence

Tags: expected-value, kullback-leibler, likelihood

Given a true normal distribution $g(x)$ with mean $\mu_G$ and variance $\sigma_G$, and a model $f(x)$, the KL divergence involves the expected log-likelihood $\mathbb{E}_G[log f(x|\theta]$. The likelihood function is given by
$$log f(x|\mathbb{\theta})=-\frac{1}{2}log(2\pi\sigma^2)-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

I read, that $\mathbb{E}_G[log f(x)|\theta]$ equals
$$-\frac{1}{2}log(2\pi\sigma^2)-\sigma_G^2+\frac{(\mu-\mu_G)^2}{\sigma^2}$$

but I do not understand how this result($\sigma_G^2+\frac{(\mu-\mu_G)^2}{\sigma^2}$) is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** 
\begin{align}
\int (x - \mu)^2 g(x) dx &= \int (x -\mu_G + \mu_G - \mu)^2 g(x) dx \\
&= \int(x - \mu_G)^2 g(x) dx + \int (\mu_G - \mu)^2 g(x) dx + 2\int (x - \mu_G)(\mu_G - \mu)g(x) dx \\
&=\sigma_G^2 + (\mu_G - \mu)^2 + 0
\end{align}